# Where to find Bash release notes or changes

Tags: bash

I need to find release notes for Bash from 3 to 4.
I could not find them neither by google.com/linux nor by default google.
I also looked unsuccessfully at gnu.org.

**Where are the release notes for Bash?**

Comment: Don't close this; it is programming related. Trying to find what changes from each version of Java and so forth is related as well as this.

Comment: Also, browse the bash git repo: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [Bash website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) you can download "Bourne again shell (BASH)".
Inside the download you can find the release notes.

---

**EDIT**: Or browse the source online, see [**NEWS**](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS) for the summaries, and [**CHANGES**](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES) for details.

For patch releases, these could be useful:

- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/
- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.0-patches/
- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.1-patches/
- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.2-patches/

Comment: Thank you! It would be great if there was a webpage where you can compare Open Source Programs' release notes between different versions.

Comment: A few additional pointers re the NEWS page at http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS: - covers ALL bash versions, in descending chronological order; - to find what's new in a particular version quickly, search for the *2nd* occurrence of `bash-{major}.{minor}`; e.g., `bash-3.2` for the version (still) current on OSX as of `OS X 10.9`; - the descriptions there are terse, so they may not be enough to fully understand the changes.

Answer (score 7):

There are two files distributed with the [source](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/bash-4.0.tar.gz): `NEWS` and `CHANGES`.  `CHANGES` documents everything, while `NEWS` summarises new features.

You can find a summary for BASH 4 [here](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/bash4), or check out section B1 of the [FAQ](ftp://ftp.cwru.edu/pub/bash/FAQ) for the latest `NEWS`.

Comment: Great; here's the link to the sources for ALL versions: http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/bash/

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS

Comment: An answer with the same link as the accepted answer is downvoted? Yeah, the voting system in SO makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Hmmm what would you suggest in its place?

Answer (score 1):

On my machine (Ubuntu 9.04) it's located at `/usr/share/doc/bash/CHANGES.gz`

Comment: No such luck on OS X (as of `OS X 10.9`); also, the documents that ARE in `/usr/share/doc/bash/` are obsolete: they refer to `bash 3.1-beta1` rather than the actually installed `bash 3.2.51`.